# Importing .bag (bathymetry) files into QGIS 3.x

Tags: qgis, gdal, bathymetry

I downloaded bathymetric data from the NOAA Bathymetric Data Viewer website: https://maps.ngdc.noaa.gov/viewers/bathymetry/

I've tried to import and view several .bag files from this website within QGIS with no luck. I have tried versions 3.10, 3.12, and 3.14. The files I tried to view were downloaded from: https://www.ngdc.noaa.gov/nos/H12001-H14000/H12053.html

I was able to import and view these files just fine in QGIS on a Mac. I, however, wasn't able to on a PC with a Windows 10 OS. I read some github forums where this seems to be a Windows issue: https://github.com/OSGeo/gdal/issues/1428

I was wondering if anyone knew a workaround to import the .bag data into QGIS to either fix the gdal issue if it is one or import the data using the python console, etc.

Here is what I see in QGIS:

[image: 1]

It loads up the data in the correct geographic loaction and lets me change the symbology but nothing is viewable.

Comment: Please list the steps you take to "import" these files.

Comment: Hi Stu, In QGIS > I open the Data Source Manager > Rasters > the bag file. I have also tried with the Add Layer > Add Raster Layer option. Both work on the Mac but don't work in Windows 10 PC. Rachel

Comment: (https://i.stack.imgur.com/51sLn.png) It is not a gdal issue. There was an OSGeo4W compilation issue but it is solved. You need to have the gdal-hdf5 package installed. Your QGIS was installed from stand-alone or network installers?

Comment: Hi Gabriel, I downloaded QGIS as a standalone from the QGIS download page: https://www.qgis.org/en/site/forusers/download.html. Where do I download the gdal-hdf5 package?

Comment: Hi Gabriel, I downloaded the OSGeo4W Network Installer (64 bit) from the QGIS website to try to download this package manually and it did not resolve the issue so if there is another way to check this is active or downloaded properly, I'd really appreciate the help. I did check the setup and it says it is installed. Also, with the photo link you posted, it shows the file with the hdf5 link and path in in the layer styling but that does not happen to my file so I'm not sure how to get QGIS to recognize this. Thank you.

Comment: Here is what I see in QGIS. It loads up the data in the correct geographic loaction and lets me change the symbology but nothing is viewable. https://imgur.com/a/sHXnifr